# Create and process options in \pgfdeclareshape

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I'm working on a small library for Registrer Transfer Level (RTL) that I'll use a lot throughout my PhD thesis. I'm designing an operator symbol that can have a bit or a bus as input and/or output. If it is a bit, the connectors should be draw as a thin line. If it is a bus, an ultra thick line. I thought of creating two options to be passed to the shape. I now how to create them, but not how to write the *if* statement to get the desired results. Following the relevant code fragments.

```
\tikzset{input type/.initial={bus}} % bus or bit string values
\tikzset{output type/.initial={bus}}

\pgfdeclareshape{operator}{
  ...
  \beforebackgroundpath{%
    % Connectors are always black
    \color{black}

    % This is the part I'm getting problems with
    % If input type is *bit*
    \pgfsetlinewidth{.5pt} % <-- ideally, it should be the thin option from tikz,
                         % but I don't know how to set it
    % If input type is *bus*
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt} % <-- should be ultra thick option

    % First input
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{a}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{north west}}
    \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}

    % Second input
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{b}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{south west}}
    \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}

    % If output type is *bit*
    \pgfsetlinewidth{.5pt}
    % If output type is *bus*
    \pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}

    % Output
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{r}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
    \pgf@process{\pgfutil@useanchor{operator}{east}}
    \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
...
}
```

It seems to be a rather easy solution, but the manual is enormous and I didn't find any clues up till now. Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT:** Added the desired output for reference
[image: Operator]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a full answer, but illustrating a trick that can be used when defining shapes so that TikZ styles can be passed to the PGF layer for the `behindbackgroundpath`. This by-passes the need for convoluted `\if...\fi` statements in the shape definition as everything can be done using styles.

In this (edited) version the symbol is placed using a node `label`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{operator}{
  \nodeparts{}
  \savedmacro\operatorparameters{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\radius{max(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)/2}%
    \addtosavedmacro\radius%
    % 
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\outersep{max(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)}%
    \addtosavedmacro\outersep%
  }
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}%
  \anchor{north}{\operatorparameters%
    \pgfpointpolar{90}{\radius+\outersep}}
  \anchor{south}{\operatorparameters%
    \pgfpointpolar{270}{\radius+\outersep}}
  \anchor{east}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{0}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}
  \anchor{west}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{180}{\radius+\outersep}}%
  \anchor{north west}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{135}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}
  \anchor{south west}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{225}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}
  \anchor{north east}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{45}{\radius+\outersep}}%
  \anchor{south east}{\operatorparameters% 
    \pgfpointpolar{315}{\radius+\outersep}}%
  \behindbackgroundpath{%
    \operatorparameters%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{135}{\radius}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{135}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{225}{\radius}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{225}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{0}{\radius}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{0}{\radius*sqrt(2)}}%
    \pgflib@sh@operator@connectors%
  }
  \backgroundpath{%
    \operatorparameters%
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\radius}%
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  operator connectors/.store in=\pgflib@sh@operator@connectors,
  operator connectors=,
}

\tikzset{%
  operator connectors/.style={
    /pgf/operator connectors={\begingroup\tikzset{#1}\tikz@finish}
  },
  operator symbol/.style 2 args={
    label={[every operator symbol/.try,#1]center:{#2}}
  },
% Defaults
  operator connectors={ultra thick, draw=black},
  every operator symbol/.style={overlay, font=\Large},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum size=1cm]
\node [shape=operator, 
   operator symbol={font=\Huge, scale=4, gray!50}{$\times$},
   operator connectors={draw=gray, line width=0.5cm},
   minimum size=2in, line width=0.5cm, 
   draw=gray!50] (s) {};
\foreach \name/\anchor in {center/above, north/above, south/below,
east/right, west/left, north east/above right, south east/below right,
north west/above left, south west/below left}
  \draw [draw=red, shift=(s.\name)] node [\anchor] {\name}
    (-.1,-.1) -- (.1,.1) (-.1,.1) -- (.1,-.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I'll implement this later into my code. Nice way to process options.

Comment: Another thing, I noticed that you've drawn the operator symbol, but thing is it can vary. In the example, I used a multiplier, but it can be any of the four arithmetic operations or comparisons (<, >, = != etc.). As the shape is basically the same, it makes no sense to have one shape for each one, but having just the symbol vary. How to implement that in your version? Also, the input and output connector can be different, it is possible to have a input bus (thick style) and a output bit (thin style), it happens with comparisons. Thank you again for your help up till now.

Comment: @WDiniz, if the symbol is always going to be a LaTeX text symbol, then you could completely remove the `\beforebackgroundpath` and just add (for example) `label={[text=white, font=\huge]center:$\times$}` to one of the operator style definitions.

Comment: Yes, it works as you said. Thank you, a really good solution. I learned a lot from your example.

Comment: Hmm, still some doubts... How I define the anchors? Inheriting them from circles does not work. I tried using the macro \radius you've defined, but got an 'illegal unit of measure' error.

Comment: @WDiniz In the original answer `\radius` was defined without `pt` at the end as it was just begin passed to `\pgfpoint` commands which just parsed the numbers and didn't need the units specified. I've updated by answer used `\pgfmathsetlenthmacro` (which adds the `pt`) and shown how the parameters defined using `\savedmacro` can be used to create anchors.

Comment: Great, that solves it! Thank you again, I've learned a lot. Just a last question, as you stated, the operators will always be some math one, how to pass it in the normal label brackets, instead of using the _label_ option? I think it'll be more practical.

Comment: @WDiniz maybe you could look at the `execute at begin node` key which can be used to insert stuff at the beginning of a node. Or the `node contents` key (PGF3.0 onwards) which is more sophisticated but can be a bit more fiddly to use.